# Selenium - Python: scroll to the element found by find_element* methods

Tags: python, selenium

I developed a selenium script, which makes automatic comments in facebook groups.
It works relatively good, but it does not execute the `click()` method if the targeted  element is not visible on the browser.
As a working around I'm using the `execute_script("window.scrollTo(x,y";)`, method, but it's not  ideal script. The piece of code that must be improved is the following:

```
text_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("UFIAddCommentInput")                            
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(100, 0);")
    text_box.click()
except:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    text_box.click()
element = driver.switch_to.active_element
element.send_keys(frase)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

It first tries for the element on the top of the page, and, if does not get to execute `click()`, it tries at the bottom.
However, there is a more effective way to scroll at the element found by the `find_element_by_class_name`method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
text_box.location_once_scrolled_into_view
text_box.click()
```

to scroll page down right to required element and click it

Comment: seems that with your solution it's working perfectly.

Comment: The best solution. Thanks!

Comment: Pylint: `W0106: Expression "driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ...).location_once_scrolled_into_view" is assigned to nothing (expression-not-assigned)`